# What is the physical meaning of a particle with wrong sign in the kinetic term?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, field-theory

I have the following Euclidean Lagrangian density:

$
\mathcal{L}=-3\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi + 8 m^2 \phi^2
$

I am using the Euclidean metric so I expect a term like $\mathcal{L}=T+V$ but here I have a "wrong" sign in the kinetic term. What does it mean? What is the mass of this field? Does it make sense to define a mass for this field?

Comment: In which context did this occur? Classically, the overall sign of the action is not important. Quantum mechanically, a field with negative kinetic energy is known as a ghost field.

Comment: Isn't it $\mathcal{L}=T- V$?

Comment: This should give an unstable field theory unless you add a nonlinear term. I think this is known in literature as tachyonic field.

Comment: If I have understood what you meant, if I don't want to know the quantize theory of this system, the fact that there is an overall sign does not have to bother me, right? However this field can be reparameterized in such a way I have the usual $\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$ term in the kinetic part and then the mass of my field is $M^2=-16/3 m^2$. Does that mean that if I had a usual Higgs potential (as like $\lambda (\phi^2-v^2)^2$, with $\lambda>0$) I get spontaneous symmetry breaking of the parity symmetry?